# How to configure mule cxf proxy client correctly

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Hi I'm playing around with a SOAP request, I am having trouble with the cxf proxy client. I'm basically sending a soap request to the http endpoint, removing the SOAP envelope, then trying to add it back it back on with the proxy client.

I'm expecting to get an unathorized response (as I'm removing the wsse headers).

However, I get the following soap response: "Response code 500 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream"
and the console logs the following (Note this is only the start of it)

WARN  2015-05-13 12:38:28,886 [[sandbox2].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}ProxyService#{http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}invoke has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Response code 500 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:194) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263) ~[cxf-api-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531) ~[cxf-rt-core-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:462) ~[cxf-rt-core-2.5.9.jar:2.5.9]

Here is my flow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.6.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8086" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8080" basePath="my-app/RetrieveAct.svc" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
    <flow name="myFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="message received #[payload] " level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <cxf:proxy-service namespace="PfPolicyService"  payload="body" doc:name="CXF"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <cxf:proxy-client payload="body" doc:name="CXF"/>
        <response>
            <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </response>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration1" path="http://localhost:8080/my-app/RetrieveAct.svc" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:header headerName="soapAction" value="getUserAcct"/>
            </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong and how to correct the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing is because your modification of the SOAP request is ending up as an invalid SOAP request, therefore the server cannot parse it and it is returning a 500 http status code.

You can use CXF's logging interceptors to be able to inspect the final result of what you're sending.

Answer (score 0):

Your mule flow seems okey to me, the proxied service might blow up for all sorts of reasons.

Add logging interceptors to the proxy client and see whether this enables you to pinpoint the issue:

```
 <cxf:proxy-client payload="body">
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor">
            <spring:property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
        </spring:bean>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor">
            <spring:property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
        </spring:bean>
    </cxf:outInterceptors> 
 </cxf:proxy-client>
```

Or alternatively, use TPCMon to capture network traffic.

Setting up a service mock and proper test case first would be a good sanity check, before doing integration testing.